# Animate an SKLabel in a Scene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uiviewanimation, sklabelnode

How can I animate the position of an SKLabel in a scene?

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
[SKView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                  delay:0.0
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^{
                                 newBestLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)+70, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)-30);
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

and

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                  delay:0.0
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^{
                                 newBestLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)+70, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)-30);
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

in viewDidLoad it starts at:

```
newBestLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)+70, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)+30);
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because **SKLabelNode** is a sub-class of **SKNode** you can use a method named **runAction:** and pass in an **SKAction** that does what you need.

```
// create an instance of SKAction
SKAction *moveLabel = [SKAction moveByX:0.0 y:30.0 duration:1.2];

// tell labelNode to run the action
[newBestLabel runAction:moveLabel];
```

It's also worth noting that the coordinate system **SpriteKit** uses, is different to that of **UIKit**. Therefor in the above code a positive x value will move to the right and a positive y value will move up!

There are many methods available to do what you need and a lot more, and are found in [SKAction Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013017-CH1-SW15)

Answer (score 3):

`SKLabelNode` does not inherit from `UIView` and this is not the way to handle animations in SpriteKit. Rather, you should handle this by creating an [SKAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) and applying it to the node:

```
SKLabelNode *label = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Avenir"];
label.position = CGPointMake(30, 200);
label.text = @"Lorem Ipsum";
[self addChild:label];

SKAction *moveLabel = [SKAction moveByX:100 y:0 duration:2.0];
[label runAction:moveLabel];
```

Not the same coordinates as in your code, but I'm sure you can take it from here.
There is also a moveTo: action if that suits your requirements better.